# Slowing down spinner based on number of images

Tags: javascript

i'm making a 360 spinner around an object, so I have 48 images stitched together, which I then load into an image, and translate this image as the user clicks and drags.

Issues i'm having is that i need to slow the movement down to the same speed regardless of the amount of images. And I also need to make it loop, not too sure i'm going about it right?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/martynball/pen/XWdXrKJ?editors=1010)

```js
Vue.component("media-360-viewer", {
  data: () => {
    return {
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/smFuq9V.jpg',
      width: 196.2890625,
      
      dragging: false,
      images: 48,
      position: null,
      start: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    startDrag: function ($event) {
      this.dragging = true;

      this.start = $event.clientX;
    },
    handleMove: function ($event) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        this.position = $event.clientX;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    offset: function () {
      return this.width * (this.start - this.position);
    }
  },
  created() {
    const component = this;

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
      component.dragging = false;
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMove);
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMove);
  },
  template: `
  <div class="media-360-viewer" ref="container">
        <p v-if="!image">Loading...</p>
        <div class="media-360-viewer__container" v-if="image" :style="{ 'width': width + 'px' }" @mousedown="startDrag">
            <img :src="image" alt="" :style="{ 'transform': 'translateX(' + offset + 'px)' }">
        </div>
    </div>
  `
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```
.media-360-viewer {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    &__container {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        touch-action: pan-y;
        user-select: none;
        & > img {
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            will-change: transform;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hi

### Problem 1

Add looping

### Solution

Change the `offset()` computed function so that it stars slicing from 0.

```
offset(){

  let offset = this.width * (this.start - this.position); 
  // --> relative offset for looping (when reached at end offset of image, starts from 0)
  let relativeOffset = offset % this.maxOffset; 
  if ((this.start - this.position) > 0) {
   // --> user dragging left so we start from end of image
   return relativeOffset + -this.maxOffset;
  } else {
   // --> user dragging to right so return relative offset as is
    return relativeOffset;
  }
},
```

Add new computed function for calculation of maxOffset.

```
// --> this function will return the max offset till which image can move
maxOffset: function() {
  return (this.images - 1) * this.width;
},
```

Also dont forget to set `position` and `start` data variables to 0.

### Problem 2

Controlling speed.

### Solution

This is a suggestion, 
you can set a data variable eg `ppf` (pixels per frame) to set number of pixels to be covered for one frame to show. For eg, in the same `offset` function 
In line `let offset = this.width * (this.start - this.position);` 
you can change to

```
let effectiveMove = Math.floor((this.start - this.position) / ppf))
let offset = this.width * effectiveMove;

// then check effectiveMove if user dragging left or right
// ------ rest of the code
```

This will ensure that a new frame will only be shown when user drags by `ppf` number of pixels.

Comment: That's all perfect thanks! However i'd like to be able rotate it, let go, the click to start rotating it again from where I left off, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can easily do it by saving the current offset on `mouseup` event and adding that as the base offset for next click & drag operation.